# Show/Hide Bottom bar icons for Mobile app

Tags: mobile

I'm working on a mobile application with subscription that has two flows:

1. **Before the login**: where an unregistered user can go around the app and view part of the content
2. **After the login**: they get access to additional functionalities

Now in this case, my application uses a bottom bar as a means of navigation. And the structure is as follows:

1. The unregistered user has 3 icons in bottom bar
2. When the user logs in the bottom bar changes and now has an additional icon along with the previous 3

Now my question is:

- Is it alright to show/hide/change the bottom bar icons depending upon the state - pre login/post login?

Some things to consider are:

- The application is B2B
- Using vertical drawer as navigation is not possible (dev issues)

Thanks

Comment: I think this question here has all the answers for you: [Don't hide or disable menu items?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items)

Answer (score 1):

I would say there's multiple way to handle news functionnality when logged-in.

Actually, a solution could be that you show ALL of the icon (consistency of your app first) but the one that he can't get in are shown as "unavailable" (in grey, color font changing, etc...). When a user click in it (or tap it), you can send him to a page saying "Log In to enjoy this app fully!" with a "I don't have an account" just in case they have to register.

For me, hiding part of a UI and changing it after a log-in is not a good idea because of the consistency of your app. Of course, you should test between the design "Everything is here" and "Things appear later" and see which one fits your users best (Using critical data that fits your hypothesis).

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how it's done.  The danger is that when the extra icon appears for a total of four icons it will not be different enough from a quick glance from three.

You should also throw in something else to ensure they see the difference. You could also

- Change the background color of the bottom bar, as an extra visual cue that they've logged in.
- Make a sound when they log in.
- Change the border color of the 4th icon.

Those are just a few ideas.

Comment: Or just animate the appearance of the 4th icon. Or even more, dim down the rest of the UI and highlight the 4th icon so to draw attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 4th icon should always be there but when the user clicks on it, it should show a login screen / empty state. This will help an existing user as well as help a new user to identify where the login is.